# Restart server based on ping response

Tags: loops, batch-file, ip, ping, restart

I've created this from a mashup of other questions/answers on this site, as well as stuff found at ss64.com

I've hammered it down to what I want, now it's just a crucial missing detail that will make it loop over and over until the connection has been established while **avoiding** constantly starting the server on each cycle.

It's massively over-engineered and horrendously made, but it's basically the culmination of all I've learned and just working it out in a way I can understand.

The main issue with it right now is if it's less than 100% packet loss, it will start the server, even if it's 80% packet loss which is too high for anything to connect or function on.

I'm looking for that crucial command to ensure the server will only start if there is 100% connection and also make sure it **wont** keep starting the server if there is 100% connection in a continued loop (which has happened far too many times, 50 instances of a server running really is a PC killer).

Here is what I have (don't laugh too hard).

```
@echo off 
title Server Restart
color 0A
cls
:start
Cls
set ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx

:ping
ping %ip% -n 5 || goto PingFail
timeout /t 8
cls
echo Ping was Successful to %ip% at %date% %time%
timeout /t 10
ping %ip% -n 5 -w 5000 && goto start
echo Moving To PingFail...
goto PingFail


:Starting
Echo Connection Established... Starting server
**Start Server.bat**
Echo Start Successful
goto start


:PingFail
cls
Echo Connection Has Failed.. looping.
timeout /t 3
goto Pingloop


:Pingloop
echo PINGLOOPING
ping %ip% -n 5 || goto Pingloop
timeout /t 15
goto Starting
```

Comment: Can you please provide more detail in 'server' and the machine you ping from and to what IP you are pinging?  Just use example IP addresses. We need to know what your current setup is.

Comment: It's a home PC pinging my visible public IP.
Server is launched from a batch file called "server.bat" in that bat it just launched the game in -batchmode with -nographics appendage.

It WILL launch multiple windows if you keep opening Server.bat.
all of them will run an active server from my IP.
(hence the need to ensure it only opens the server if the internet connection is established) it ought to have a function to close existing processes of the same type to be honest.

Comment: Here is an example of it running with an altered IP.
https://i.gyazo.com/fe2541419f88d2ff728429cf8d39a98c.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of servers are we talking about? And you are aware that most firewalls block ping request by default right?
You can use: https://uptimerobot.com/ and use their API to get valid information.

If you want to be sure you that you have a connection to the outside world you can check for 0% loss like this:

```
ping -n 1 -4 www.google.com | grep "0% loss"
```

I have never seen 80% or 60% loss but of course you can change 0% to whatever percentage. Though pinging your own public IP doesn't mean you have a working internet connection. You need to ping the 'world' not your home.

Comment: Hi, this is a simple server for a very small simple game.
My firewall has everything unblocked (in fact totally disabled).
The ping is pinging my own public IP address since the server uses direct IP to connect.

Comment: wait what? you are pinging yourself? Ooh you mean, you are checking if you have a working internet connection or...?

Comment: Yeah, the idea is I can leave the batch going and it will continue pinging looking for net drop offs and then when it does drop, checking it until the connection is established, at which point it will start the server on its own.

Sounds simple in theory right? 

I know there's 3rd party software I could use and achieve the same result, but this is largely a learning exercise for me as well as being functional.

Comment: Hey! thanks for that.
It seems obvious now to ping google.com but I was assuming it would work all the same pinging the public IP address, head scratching began when it was actually receiving packets from the public IP - with the internet switch off.

However, I can't seem to get 'grep 0% loss" working..

Here's how I have it currently.

`timeout /t 5
ping %ip% -n 5 -w 3000 | grep "0% loss"
timeout /t 15
goto Starting`

the %ip% points to www.google.com.

Comment: Hi @Cinn What OS are you running? And where is the `timeout /t 5` for? You should not ping more then 3 times to Google. They don't really mind but you only need 3 for good validation. You can also remove the -w 3000. It's not realy needed here don't you think? Or do you have a really old internet connection? 
`ping -4 www.google.com -n 3 | find /i "0%"`
this seems to work on Windows.

Comment: runnin win7 Pro OS, the timeouts are my workaround for instead of using `-w 3000`, the concept of the program is to run constantly, so by adjusting the `/t 5` I can't slow down the frequency of the pings.

I was doing 5 pings to ensure there was 100% connection, I wouldn't want the program launching a server if there was 80% packet loss once but 100% 4 other times.

Comment: Currently I have:

`@echo off
title Restart
:start
Cls
set ip=www.google.com

:Pingcheck
echo Checking ping..
ping -4 www.google.com -n 3 | find /i "0%" || goto Loss
pause

:NoLoss
echo We found 0 packet loss, at %ip% on %date% at %time%
pause
goto start
:Loss
echo We found some packet loss.
pause`

Is there any explanation for why it's returning "we found 0% packet loss" despite the internet being manually disconnected?

It's also not issuing the ping command, rather, just stating that packets were sent and received, while no

Comment: Hi @Cinn, 0% package loss means the internet is UP. 100% package loss mean its dead. So, change `find /i "100%"` and your good.

Comment: Hi @Digital Human 
My bad, even after correcting, it is still reporting packetloss found with internet established.
https://i.gyazo.com/8107275eecc8384095e06afb56e9d38c.png

Is findstr struggling with the '%' ? I've noticed the google.com IP is xxx.xx.200.100, could it be ignoring the '100%' and just picking up the IP?

Comment: @Cinn This pingtest works. https://gist.github.com/digitalhuman/d54fac48339b3c2165e0aecab3eec43f